# How to get "my" VHOST in code executed by PerPostConfigRequire?

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl2

I'm hosting multiple instances of the same web app in different versions using the same instance of HTTPd and one `VHOST` per instance/version of web app currently. I would like to use mod_perl's `PostConfigRequire` to implement a handler pre-loading all those instances during server startup instead of relying on mod_perl's registry-facilities per request, as is done currently. The latter [breaks](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-modperl/201907.mbox/%3C1116164701.20190731193313%40am-soft.de%3E) in case of too many concurrent requests and according to some tests, that problem doesn't occur anymore in case things get pre-loaded.

Because of the different versions of my web app, I need to use `PerlOptions +Parent` to provide each `VHOST` with its individual Perl interpreter pool. Additionally I can easily configure `PerlPostConfigRequire` per `VHOST`, but pre-loading needs to take into account which `VHOST` that handler is currently executed in. Within that handler I need to only load those files associated with some concrete `VHOST`.

The problem is that I'm having trouble how to find the `VHOST` currently executing that handler. In that past I have implemented something similar per request by looking at the currently requested URL and comparing that to `VHOST` configs, but I don't have a request now. `Apache2::ServerUtil->server()` is not providing my `VHOST`, but it's available at all e.g. using `Apache2::Directive::conftree()->lookup('VirtualHost')`. Only that I don't know which one is the one containing `PerlPostConfigRequire` currently executed. I'm pretty sure that `PerlPostConfigRequire` really gets executed per `VHOST`, because I get debugging output scaling with the number of `VHOST`s configured as well.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which came into my mind is using environment variables per VHOST like in the following example. `PerlSetVar` doesn'T work because it's per request only and not available during startup of the web server.

```
PerlSetEnv SOME_ID "0c8c1236-86de-4483-9d4b-999e2cfd17c1"
PerlPostConfigRequire "Some.pm"
```

Each VHOST gets it's own ID and that environment variable seems to be uniquely available during execution of the configured package:

```
[Mon Aug 05 20:50:32.181559 2019] [:warn] [pid 17736:tid 704] [...]: 0c8c1236-86de-4483-9d4b-999e2cfd17c1: 1
[Mon Aug 05 20:50:32.836195 2019] [:warn] [pid 17736:tid 704] [...]: 9dc691d6-794a-4095-852e-e596cabf43d5: 1
[Mon Aug 05 20:50:34.180453 2019] [:warn] [pid 17736:tid 704] [...]: 0c8c1236-86de-4483-9d4b-999e2cfd17c1: 2
[Mon Aug 05 20:50:34.830098 2019] [:warn] [pid 17736:tid 704] [...]: 9dc691d6-794a-4095-852e-e596cabf43d5: 2
```

The logging code:

```
my $server = Apache2::ServerUtil->server();
   $server->warn(__PACKAGE__ . ": $ENV{'SOME_ID'}: " . Apache2::ServerUtil::restart_count());
```

With that in mind, one can get all VHOSTs and search for the ID they define. It's important to note that `lookup` is not of much help here, it doesn't seem to support searching for `PerlSetEnv` directly, but one needs to implement that on hash refs returned for the VHOSTs manually:

```
my $confTree  = Apache2::Directive::conftree();
my @vhosts    = $confTree->lookup('VirtualHost');
```

Each result is a hash ref containing keys and values like the following:

```
$VAR1 = {\n          'PerlSetEnv' => 'AMS_MOD_PERL_PRE_LOADING_ID "9dc691d6-794a-4095-852e-e596cabf43d5"',\n[...]

'PerlSetEnv' => [\n  '"AMS_MOD_PERL_PRE_LOADING_ID" "9dc691d6-794a-4095-852e-e596cabf43d5"',\n '"murks" "test"'\n ],
```

The structure of the hash ref depends on the actual config, so it might contain additional child hash refs I guess. Any better ideas welcome...